# Is there a way to do delta updates for container images w/o a registry?

Tags: docker, embedded, container, podman

In the context of a non-connected machine which has limited space available, is there a way to update the container image using a diff/patch mechanism?

Like you call `docker pull` but on a binary patch where a new image is created based on the original image + the additional layers brought in by the patch.

Thank you!